# I can't catch specific browser logged errors from an AJAX call. Is catching these even possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, error-handling

I'm trying to break an AJAX call in as many ways as I can to anticipate many specific errors. Using the error callback in jQuery ajax, doesn't give me specific enough information compared to what the browser logs (which I would like to catch). I would receive the same generic information (status of 0 with a statusText of "error") for these two errors from Chrome in the error callback:

1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'some url' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
2. GET http://google.com/ net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Right now my code is similar to the answer in [how can i handle multiple ajax errors in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697985/how-can-i-handle-multiple-ajax-errors-in-jquery). I would like it to address more specific errors, but I suspect it's not possible to catch the specific errors the browser logs.

Is it even possible to catch these errors?

Note: Wrapping the call in a try-catch does not work either. Using vanilla XHR doesn't provide specific error information either.

Answer (score 0):

That answer refers to handling the `.status` object, which will only contain a number. If you want to handle error messages, use the `.responseText`, and either `JSON.parse()` it or use `indexOf()` to check on the exceptions you want to use. You can also use the `thrownError` string:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log("thrownError: " + thrownError);
  }   
});
```